# i want to display the product_name from the other table that has the same product_id laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Controller:

```
public function OrderHistory(){

    $user_id = Auth::User()->id;
    $orders = Order::with('ordersz')->where('user_id',$user_id)->get();
    return view('users.order_history')->with(compact('orders'));
}
```

**Blade page:**

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Order ID</th>
            {{--<th>Quantity</th>--}}
            <th>Ordered Products</th>
            <th> Quantity</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Order Date</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($orders as $order)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$order->id}}</td>
                <td>
                    {{--@foreach($userCart as $cart)--}}
                        {{--{{$cart->product_name}}<br>--}}
                    {{--@endforeach--}}

                    @foreach($order->ordersz as $pro)
                        {{$pro->product_id}}<br>// here im displaying the product_id but i want the product name
                    @endforeach
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{--@foreach($userCart as $cart)--}}
                    {{--{{$cart->product_name}}<br>--}}
                    {{--@endforeach--}}

                    @foreach($order->ordersz as $pro)
                        {{$pro->quantity}}<br>
                    @endforeach
                </td>
                <td> {{$order->total_amount}}</td>
                <td> {{$order->created_at}}</td>
                <td>View Details</td>

            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm getting the orders history by `user id` and I'm displaying the **product_id** in the **orders_product table**. Now I want to display the **product_name** from **products table**, I have foreign key for **products_id**

Comment: Do you have the relationships set up in the models?

Comment: yes sir, i have

Comment: You need to post more of your database schema. Please include the models in question and the relations you have defined.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to define the needed [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships) within your *Order* model:

```
function product() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Product');
}
```

Obviously, this implies you have a model for Product, what you should have.

Then within your view you may retrieve your product like follow, thank to dynamic properties:

```
$pro->product->name;
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.order_product_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `products` where `products`.`order_product_id` in (2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)) im having this errors

Comment: i dont have any  idea about the needed relationship you are stating sire

Answer (score 0):

If you have a relation on Orderz called product its fairly simple.

Where you eager load `orderz` you want to add products like so:

```
$orders = Order::with('ordersz.product')->where('user_id',$user_id)->get();
```

and then in the blade on the line with your comment you would just do:

```
{{$pro->product->name}}<br>
```

Comment: i have three tables order table ,and product table, and orders_product table, in my orders_product table i have only product_id foreign key.

Comment: the only relation i make is ny my Order model    public function ordersz(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\OrderProduct','order_id');//order_id can be found on our OrderProduct tbl
    }
and in my product model   public function ord(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\OrderProduct','product_id');//product_id can be found on our OrderProduct tbl
    }

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.order_product_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `products` where `products`.`order_product_id` in (2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12))  im having this errors